# Android - gson.toJson throws StackOverFlowError on ArrayList<OverlayItem>

Tags: java, android, json, sharedpreferences, gson

I'm trying to create a JSON string of my `ArrayList` containing `OverlayItems` (`OverlayItem` is a type of osmdroid library that I'm using). The reason I'm doing this is because I want to keep this `ArrayList` of `OverlayItems` when the Android app is closed, the data must be kept (and the gson-solution seemed like a nice way of achieving this since you can't just add an `ArrayList` to `SharedPreferences`).

This throws a `StackOverflowException` error, I think it cannot resolve the type. I looked up my problem and many answers on other threads suggest that this is caused by a circular reference. I don't think that this is the case however with the `OverlayItems`, they are built like this:

```
OverlayItem(String aUid, String aTitle, String aDescription, IGeoPoint aGeoPoint)
```

IGeoPoint is also a type of osmdroid, it just holds a longitude and latitude int.

The code for the serializing is this:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor ed = mPrefs.edit();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(waypointMarkers);
ed.putString("waypoints", json);
ed.commit();

// wayPointmarkers is the ArrayList<OverlayItem>
```

Why am I getting these errors?:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:381)
        at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:376)
        at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:381)
        at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:376)
         ...
```

### Edit 1

I've added InstanceCreators for both OverlayItem and IGeoPoint (neither of them has a default no-args constructor):

```
class OverlayItemInstanceCreator implements InstanceCreator<OverlayItem> {
    public OverlayItem createInstance(Type type) {
        return new OverlayItem(null,null,null,null);
    }
}

class IGeoPointItemInstanceCreator implements InstanceCreator<IGeoPoint> {
    public IGeoPoint createInstance(Type type) {
        return new IGeoPoint() {
            @Override
            public int getLatitudeE6() {
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public int getLongitudeE6() {
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public double getLatitude() {
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public double getLongitude() {
                return 0;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

And I'm registering them with this code:

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(OverlayItem.class, new OverlayItemInstanceCreator());
    gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(IGeoPoint.class, new IGeoPointItemInstanceCreator());
    Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
    String json = gson.toJson(waypointMarkers);
    ed.putString("waypoints", json);
```

But I'm still getting the same errors. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to serialize classes without default constructor (e.g. [GeoPoint implementation](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/master/osmdroid-third-party/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/google/wrapper/GeoPoint.java) doesn't have one). Gson can't do it without additional work (actually can, but in some quirky manner and it's unsafe).

[Check out this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18645050/is-default-no-args-constructor-mandatory-for-gson), it can be helpful.

Comment: I see. I assume that the gson-solution is not a good idea then in my case? I don't like the other solutions mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057845/save-arraylist-to-sharedpreferences

Comment: Hm, why not? Technically you just need to do additional work by defining InstanceCreator. All docs can be found there http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/InstanceCreator.html

Comment: I've updated my question with InstanceCreator code, do you have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: So, I did some tests. OverlayItem depends on Drawable. I suggest to use some simplified object to store the data.

Comment: The reason I wanted to store these OverlayItems was because they contained all the data I wanted, I need the Uid, the title, the description, and the geopoint. I guess I can make objects to hold all this data, then the Drawable dependancy should be resolved