# Gson not honouring rules in builder

Tags: java, json, gson, builder

I have a class called `Student` which has some required fields and others are optional. To make sure no object of the class `Student` is created without having provided required fields, I'm using a builder. Here's the class `Student`:

```
package prj1.dob;

import java.util.Date;

public class Student {
   private final int id;
   private final String name;
   private final String surname;
   private final Date dob;
   private final Double gpa;
   private final String email;

   public static class Builder {
      //required fields
      private int id;
      private String name;
      private String surname;

      //optional fields
      private Date dob;
      private Double gpa;
      private String email;

      public Builder(int id, String name, String surname) {
         this.id = id;
         this.name = name;
         this.surname = surname;
      }

      public Builder dob(Date dob) {
         this.dob = dob;
         return this;
      }

      public Builder gpa(Double gpa) {
         this.gpa = gpa;
         return this;
      }

      public Builder email(String email) {
         this.email = email;
         return this;
      }

      public Student build() throws Exception {
         return new Student(this);
      }
    }

    private Student(Builder b) throws Exception {
         this.id = b.id;
         this.name = b.name;
         this.surname = b.surname;
         this.dob = b.dob;
         this.gpa = b.gpa;
         this.email = b.email;
         validate();
     }

   private void validate() throws Exception {
      if (id < 10 || name == null || surname == null) {
        throw new Exception("You should provide an id, name and surname.");
   }
 }

 @Override
 public String toString() {
  return "Student [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", surname=" + surname + ", dob=" + dob + ", gpa=" + gpa  + ", email=" + email + "]";
    }
}
```

Having this implementation of the class `Student`, I would expect that there should not be a way of creating an invalid `Student` object (i.e. required fields should not be `null`). However, the code provided below does not throw an `Exception` and when I print the contents of `Student` the required fields are `null`.

JSON object:

```
{"id":-1,"name":null,"surname":null,"dob":null,"gpa":null,"email":null}
```

Here's the code that creates a POJO from JSON:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
  try {
       String param = request.getParameter("std").toString();
       Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").serializeNulls().create();
       Student student = gson.fromJson(param, Student.class);
       // student.validate();
       response.getWriter().write(student.toString());
  } catch (Exception ex) { 
       response.getWriter().write(ex.getMessage());
  }
}
```

I would expect it to throw an `Exception` but it creates an object of `Student` and when printed this is the contents:

```
Student [id=-1, name=null, surname=null, dob=null, gpa=null, email=null]
```

*Is this a bug in the Gson library or am I not doing something right?*

If this is how it should be, then what's the point of using the **builder** approach when one can still create an object of the class without following the rules (providing the required fields)?

Comment: Gson does not know anything about your ``Builder``....

Comment: what is the value of param  variable ?

Comment: ``param`` is the JSON string that @A2H mentioned: ``{"id":-1,"name":null,"surname":null,"dob":null,"gpa":null,"email":null}``

Comment: The value of the `param` variable is the JSON object provided above.

Comment: GSON doesn't know about your builder, If you want functionality like required or optional fields, then you have to define your own custom deserializer for that class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GSON uses [reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18645050/is-default-no-args-constructor-mandatory-for-gson) and not your builder to construct the `Student`.

While you can't stop other users of Student creating stuff willy-nilly using reflection, you can supply an [`JsonDeserializer`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.2.3/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonDeserializer.html) which knows the rules for `Student` and creates one using your builder.