# Kotlin object deserialization with GSON

Tags: gson, kotlin

I have a class

```
class ThreadComment(
    banned: Int,
    closed: Int,
    comment: String?,
    date: String?,
    email: String?,
    files: ArrayList<File>?,
    lasthit: Int,
    name: String?,
    num: String?,
    op: Int,
    parent: String?,
    postsCount: Int,
    sticky: Int,
    subject: String?,
    tags: String?,
    timestamp: Int,
    trip: String?) : Comment(banned, closed, comment, date, email, files, lasthit, name, num, op, parent, postsCount, sticky, subject, tags, timestamp, trip) {

val answers: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()}
```

Parent class looks like

```
open class Comment(
    @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("banned")
    val banned: Int = 0,

    @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("closed")
    val closed: Int = 0,

    @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("comment")
    val comment: String? = null,

    @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("date")
    val date: String? = null,

    @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("email")
    val email: String? = null,

    @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("files")
    val files: ArrayList<File>? = null,

    @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("lasthit")
    val lasthit: Int = 0,

    @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("name")
    val name: String? = null,

    @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("num")
    val num: String? = null,

    @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("op")
    val op: Int = 0,

    @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("parent")
    val parent: String? = null,

    @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("posts_count")
    val postsCount: Int = 0,

    @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("sticky")
    val sticky: Int = 0,

    @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("subject")
    val subject: String? = null,

    @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("tags")
    val tags: String? = null,

    @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("timestamp")
    val timestamp: Int = 0,

    @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("trip")
    val trip: String? = null) : Serializable
```

But after deserialization with GSON answers field is null. 
[image: Debugger]

I also tried to put initiation into init{}, but it still null, by lazy throws an exception about calling lazy.getValue on a null object reference

Comment: Show us the json please.

Comment: @miensol json objects don't contain field "answers". But I also triyed to use ExclusionStrategy for serialization and deserialization to exclude this field.

Comment: A side note:  Jackson (JSON deser) has Kotlin support for dealing with Kotlin constructors and use cases via https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin ... for other Java libraries you should check for similar because they do not understand all concepts Kotlin nor take advantage of them.  You will end up doing unnatural Kotlin (i.e. the answer from @miensol) just to satisfy your deser library.  unfortuneatly GSON is not extensible in a way that allows it to be friendlier to Kotlin.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18645050/is-default-no-args-constructor-mandatory-for-gson) [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) can *unsafely* handle no-args constructor scenarios. It does so by leveraging [`UnsafeAllocator`](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/internal/UnsafeAllocator.java) that in turn uses [`allocateInstanсe(Class p)`](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/sun/misc/Unsafe.html#allocateInstance(Class)). This means that when there is no no-args constructor and there is no custom [instance creator](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#TOC-Writing-an-Instance-Creator) registered the object created by `Gson` **will have fields initialized with their declared types default values**.

To resolve that either add a no-arg constructor i.e

```
private constructor() : this(-1, -1, "", "", "", null, -1, "", "", -1, null, -1, -1, null, null, -1, null)
```

Or add default parameter values to your primary constructor like so:

```
class ThreadComment(
        banned: Int = -1,
        closed: Int = -1,
        comment: String? = null,
        date: String? = null,
        email: String? = null,
        files: ArrayList<File>? = null,
        lasthit: Int = -1,
        name: String? = null,
        num: String? = null,
        op: Int = -1,
        parent: String? = null,
        postsCount: Int = -1,
        sticky: Int = -1,
        subject: String? = null,
        tags: String? = null,
        timestamp: Int = -1,
        trip: String? = null
) : Comment(banned, closed, comment, date, email, files, lasthit, name, num, op, parent, postsCount, sticky, subject, tags, timestamp, trip) {
    val answers: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
}
```

Answer (score 9):

That´s weird, I just used @SerializedName normally as in Java with a data class and it worked:

```
data class(@SerializedName("my_string_value") val myStringValue: String, @SerializedName("my_int_value") val myIntValue: Int)
```