# Gson Deserialization with Kotlin, Initializer block not called

Tags: gson, kotlin

My initializer block is working perfectly fine when I create my Object

```
class ObjectToDeserialize(var someString: String = "") : Serializable {
    init{
        someString += " initialized"
    }
}
```

this way:

```
@Test
fun createObject_checkIfInitialized() {
      assertEquals("someString initialized",ObjectToDeserialize("someString").someString)
}
```

But when I deserialize the object with Gson, the initializer block does not get executed:

```
@Test
fun deserializeObject_checkIfInitialized(){
    val someJson: String = "{\"someString\":\"someString\" }"
    val jsonObject = Gson().fromJson(someJson, ObjectToDeserialize::class.java)

    assertEquals("someString initialized",jsonObject.someString)

    // Expected :someString initialized
    // Actual   :someString
}
```

I think that gson is creating the object in a different way than by executing the primary constructor. Is it nevertheless possible to have something similar like initializer blocks?

---

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Gson is intended for usage with pure Java and doesn't interpret Kotlin primary constructors properly.

If there is a default no-argument constructor, it is called (in your case, there is one: the primary constructor with default value `""` for `someString`), [otherwise Gson calls no constructor at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18645050/is-default-no-args-constructor-mandatory-for-gson).

Then Gson sets the property values (also, it bypasses actual setters of Kotlin properties and sets the fields directly, which may sometimes lead to unexpected behavior).

---

As an alternative, you can use [jackson-module-kotlin](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin), it should work good in your case (it understands Kotlin primary constructors, uses Kotlin setters and supports default parameter values as well since `2.8.x`).

This example compares jackson-module-kotlin and [Kotson](https://github.com/SalomonBrys/Kotson) behavior:

```
class SomeClass(val id: Int = -1) {
    init { println("init $id") }
}

class SomeClassNoDefault(val id: Int) {
    init { println("init $id") }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val mapper = jacksonObjectMapper()
    val gson = Gson()

    val idDefault = "{}"
    val id123 = "{\"id\": 123 }"

    println("jackson-module-kotlin, { }:")
    val o1 = mapper.readValue<SomeClass>(idDefault)
    println("after construction: ${o1.id}\n")

    println("jackson-module-kotlin, { \"id\" = 123 }:")
    val o2 = mapper.readValue<SomeClass>(id123)
    println("after construction: ${o2.id}\n")

    println("kotson, { }:")
    val o3 = gson.fromJson<SomeClass>(idDefault)
    println("after construction: ${o3.id}\n")

    println("kotson, { \"id\" = 123 }:")
    val o4 = gson.fromJson<SomeClass>(id123)
    println("after construction: ${o4.id}\n")

    println("---\n")

    println("jackson-module-kotlin, no default value, { \"id\" = 123 }:")
    val o5 = mapper.readValue<SomeClassNoDefault>(id123)
    println("after construction: ${o5.id}\n")

    println("kotson, no default value, { \"id\" = 123 }:")
    val o6 = gson.fromJson<SomeClassNoDefault>(id123)
    println("after construction: ${o6.id}\n")
}
```

The output is

> ```
> jackson-module-kotlin, { }:
> init -1
> after construction: -1
>
> jackson-module-kotlin, { "id" = 123 }:
> init 123
> after construction: 123
>
> kotson, { }:
> init -1
> after construction: -1
>
> kotson, { "id" = 123 }:
> init -1
> after construction: 123
>
> ---
>
> jackson-module-kotlin, no default value, { "id" = 123 }:
> init 123
> after construction: 123
>
> kotson, no default value, { "id" = 123 }:
> after construction: 123
> ```

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue with Gson. My data class had some serialized paraments and few non serialized. And I wanted to make my non serialized parameters with default values. The simplest solution I found is to make my non serialized parameters optional. Here is my workaround:

```
data class MyClass(
@SerializedName("name") val name: String // All Serialize goes here
) { // Non serialized
    var status: String?
        get {
            return if (field == null) {
                "Nice status"
            } else {
                field
            }
        }
}
```