# Kotlin data class Gson serialization issue

Tags: int, boolean, gson, kotlin, data-class

Im a little bit confused for my kotlin class didn't work as expected:

the data class used to check update info:

```
data class UpdateInfo constructor(//kotlin class
    val description: String,
    val force: Int,
    val platform: String,
    val title: String,
    val url: String,
    @SerializedName("version")
    val versionCode: Int = 0
) : Serializable {
    val isForceUpdate = force == 1
}
```

also a util used to decode object form json:

```
public class JsonUtil {//java class
    private static final Gson gson;
    static {
        BooleanAdapter booleanAdapter = new BooleanAdapter();
        gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .serializeNulls()
            .disableHtmlEscaping()
            .setLenient()
            .registerTypeAdapter(Boolean.class, booleanAdapter)
            .registerTypeAdapter(boolean.class, booleanAdapter)
            .create();
    }
}
```

when I test it:

```
val json = "{\"force\"=\"1\"}"
val info = JsonUtil.fromJsonObject(json, UpdateInfo::class.java)
println(info)
println(info.force == 1)
println(info.isForceUpdate)
```

I get:

```
UpdateInfo(description=null, force=1, platform=null, title=null, url=null,versionCode=0)
true
false
```

What?? info.isForceUpdate = false ???
Then I tried `lateinit` or `by lazy{}`, still not works.
So, what should I do..I'm useing `info.force==1` directly now,but I still want to know why this happend.

Comment: Please check if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39962284/gson-deserialization-with-kotlin-initializer-block-not-called

Comment: If you want your constructor to be called properly by the serialization library (instead of using `Unsafe` to instantiate it), you may be interested in [Moshi](https://medium.com/square-corner-blog/kotlins-a-great-language-for-json-fcd6ef99256b), which in some ways can be seen as a successor to Gson.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the property `val isForceUpdate = force == 1` is computed once at the instantiation of the class and then stored in a field. Because Gson is using [`Unsafe`](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/internal/UnsafeAllocator.java) to instantiate the class, the field is set to its default value `false`.

All you have to do to fix this is change the property to a computed property:

```
val isForceUpdate get() = force == 1
```

so that the value is computed on any call and not stored in a field.